# Join two tables through third one with two foreign keys

Tags: django, postgresql, foreign-keys, django-queryset, django-orm

I have three tables:

```
class Bank(models.Model):
    ...

class Deposit(models.Model):
    ...

class DepositProposal(models.Model):
    percent = models.FloatField()
    deposit = models.ForeignKey(Deposit)
    bank = models.ForeignKey(Bank)
```

Banks can participate in deposit auctions by applying the DepositProposal instance. How can I filter Banks that do not participate in Deposit?
Found that I should use two left join but I didn't come across it using PosgtreSQL.

Comment: Can you explain more about "which bank hasn't participated yet?" How does that relate to your models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know the deposits in which a bank does not participate:

1- Add a related_name to deposit and bank:

```
class DepositProposal(models.Model):
    percent = models.FloatField()
    deposit = models.ForeignKey(Deposit, related_name = "proposals")
    bank = models.ForeignKey(Bank, related_name = "proposals")
```

2- Get the bank that you want to check:

```
bank = Bank.objects.first() #For example, the first bank
```

3- Get the queryset:

```
deposits = Deposit.objects.exclude(proposals__bank = bank)
```

EDIT:

If you want to know the banks that not participate on a specific deposit:

```
deposit = Deposit.objects.first() #For example, the first deposit
banks = Bank.objects.exclude(proposals__deposit = deposit)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you! Understand now how to use double underscore syntax.